# Override layout using data binding on android

Tags: android, layout, binding, overriding, android-databinding

I'm building an android library with data binding features, but I want to other applications use my library and overwrite some layouts (builted with data binding) but when this applications overwrite this layouts there is a class cast exception during my Fragment's initialization.

Something like:

```
public abstract class FragmentQuestionsBinding extends ViewDataBinding **implements SomeInterfaceHere** {
...
}
```

Is there a way of "interfacing" a DataBinding class in order to overwrite its layout in an app avoiding this class cast exception?

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer was here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#custom_binding_class_names.

I needed to specify the original Binding class in the  tag in my overridden layout.

```
<data class="com.package.databinding.FragmentQuestionsBinding">
</data>
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, this creates the class with the given name, but then there are duplicate classes...